# How to make a table header fixed when scrolling in codename one

Tags: header, row, codenameone, fixed

I need a scrolling table with a fixed header. I tried a borderlayout.center. and checked table scrolling methods , but failed. First row keep moving out of screen.

I really appreciate help.

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the code that you tried to the post? The two table approach should work pretty easily

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you create two tables and place one in the north and one in the center of a border layout. The north one contains only the header and the south one contains only the body.

The one important thing is to override the constraint method in the table and return identical values for cell widths. That way everything aligns.

Comment: I was thinking about that as a last resort, but I just thought that it could be a function call like in Swing, thank you , I will try the solution.